# Using R, how to have the chisq.test function read the 4 column entries to get the proper statistics

Tags: r, dataframe, chi-squared

I have this dataset

```
structure(list(`total primary - yes RS` = 138L, `total primary - no RS` = 29L, 
`total secondary- yes rs` = 6L, `total secondary- no rs` = 0L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


`total primary - yes RS`|`total primary - no RS`|`total secondary- yes rs`|`total secondary- no rs`
                   138                      29                         6                      0
```

I'm not asking to convert it like this but use this as a reference for alignment of the dataset

```
                   Col1                     Col2
 Row1 `total primary - yes RS|`total secondary- yes rs`
 Row2 `total primary - no RS`|`total secondary- no rs`

                   Col1                     Col2 
 Row1                 138                         6
 Row2                  29                         0
```

I tried to run this but i don't how i should order this. I got the wrong result using the dataset like this.

```
 chisq.test(sample[ , c("total primary - yes RS" , "total primary - no RS"  , "total secondary- yes rs" ,"total secondary- no rs")])
```

and the results i expect are

```
X-squared = 0.31654, df = 1, p-value = 0.5737
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to `unlist` and create a `matrix` of `dim` 2 x 2 before applying the `chisq.test`

```
chisq.test(matrix(unlist(df1), ncol  = 2))
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

#data:  matrix(unlist(df1), ncol = 2)
#X-squared = 0.31654, df = 1, p-value = 0.5737
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`total primary - yes RS` = 138L, `total primary - no RS` = 29L, 
    `total secondary- yes rs` = 6L, `total secondary- no rs` = 0L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: How did it know in what order to put the columns in their proper place, 1st column goes [1,1], 2nd column goes to [1,2], 3rd column goes to [2.1] and 4th column goes [2.2]. Is the order left, top to bottom always assumed?

Comment: @user35131 with `matrix`, by default it is column order.  So, by `unlist`ing we get a vector of 4 elements, and by constructing a matrix by specifying number of cols = 2, the first two elements will be in the first column and the second column include 3rd and 4th.  So, it is in the order that you wanted

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what i wanted.